# Where can I find firmware updates for Nikon and how do I install them?

Tags: nikon, firmware

I've been seeing for a while that there are firmware updates for cameras.  In my current case I have a Nikon D90.  Where can I find firmware updates and how do I update them?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nikon Support Site](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13783/~/current-firmware-downloads-available-for-nikon-products) lists all the firmware for their cameras. Download [v1.0.2](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17162) for the D90 using that link.

I believe the steps are as follows:

1. Unzip the file
2. Run the setup routine and follow the instructions
3. When finished navigate to your desktop
4. Locate the Nikon folder
5. Inside this folder copy the NKLD01002.BIN file to the root of the memory card
6. Turn on camera and go to the menu
7. Go to the setup menu (the wrench looking symbol)
8. Select Update
9. Confirm firmware upgrade (e: 1.000 -> 1.002)
10. Click Yes
11. DO NOT TOUCH THE CAMERA while the firmware updates.
12. Message appears saying firmware updated and that camera needs to be turned off
13. Turn camera off
14. Turn camera on and navigate to the firmware menu option
15. Ensure version number is now the new version (ie: 1.002)

NOTE: I have already upgraded mine, so you may actually be prompted at step 3.

**Update 1**

You can follow the instructions here: [Updating Distortion Control Lens Data](http://nikonimglib.com/dcdata/manual/En/lensprofile_win_en_ABF.html) If you want picture based instructions.

Comment: This seems to be just a computer update, not a camera update.  But I get the idea.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @denislexic - There is a firmware file in there see my update

Comment: There should probably be a step between #5 and #6 that clarifies the memory card should be removed from the computer and inserted into the camera's memory card slot. Also, the link is dead.